# Ampersand was not expecting error while loading an array from a variable

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, scripting, export-to-pdf

I am new to batch scripting.I was trying with the tabcmd get command in the batch script.The url parameters are seperated by &.
eg:

```
 set param=id=%%a^&name=%%b^&addr=%%c idno=%%a^&fullname=%%b^&address=%%c
```

I am getting %%a ,%%b,%c values from a csv file using for loop. But before that i need to load the the above param variable to an array like this

```
a[0]=id%%20num=%%a&name=%%b&addr=%%c a[1]=idno=%%a&fullname=%%b&address=%%c
```

below is the for loop i used

```
for %%a in (%param%) do (
set d[%p%]=%%a)
```

getting the error & was not expected at this time.

tried the below as well

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
for %%a in (!param!) do (
echo %%a
set d[%p%]=%%a
```

getting only this `id%%20num` in the first iteration from the for loop.

I even tried "param",then the entire value with quotes is retrieved but after removing the " using !param:"=! the %%a,%%b,%%c are not getting replaced with the actual values read from the file down the line.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------details requested by Comp.
I have a config.bat file where iam passing the parameters.
config.bat

```
set N=2
set FilterFile=\productfilter.csv  \empfilter.csv                                                  
set Filterworksheet=/views/xxxxxx/productFilters.csv /views/xxxxxx/empFilters.csv
set param=product%%20num=%%c^&:product%%20Name=%%a^&:product%%20id=%%b emp%%20num=%%c^&:emp%%20Name=%%a^&:emp%%20id=%%b
```

Script.bat

```
@echo off

call  config.bat
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
:check
set /a counter=1
if %counter% LEQ %N% GOTO :array
if %counter% GTR %N% GOTO :checkparam
:array
for %%a in ("%Filterworksheet%") do (

set a[%counter%]=%%a

echo !a[%counter%]!
set /a counter=%counter%+1

goto :check

)
:checkparam
set /a p=1
if %p% LEQ %N% GOTO :arrayparam
if %p% GTR %N% GOTO :LOGIC
:arrayparam
for %%a in (%param%) do (
echo %%a
set d[%p%]=%%a
set /a p=%p%+1
goto :checkparam
)

:LOGIC
SET /a c=1
SET /a counter=1
set /a p=1
:COUNTER
if %c% LEQ %N% GOTO :GET
if %c% GTR %N% GOTO :EXIT
:GET
echo !a[%counter%]!
REM -gets the filter worksheet in csv
"tabcmd.exe" get !a[%counter%]! --filename %FilterFile%

for /f "tokens=1-26 delims=," %%a in (%FilterFile%)  do (

ECHO !d[%p%]!
)
SET /A counter=%counter%+1
SET /A c=%c%+1
SET /A p=%p%+1

goto :counter
EndLocal
```

%FilterFile% -\productfilter.csv has the below data.The data can have N number of rows.

```
productname   productid      productnum    
xyz            11               23
qqq            12               34
```

So in the first iteration the echo should give the below output

```
product%%20num=11^&:product%%20Name=xyz^&:product%%20id=23
product%%20num=12^&:product%%20Name=qqq^&:product%%20id=34
```

In the second iteration,%FilterFile% -\empfilter.csv has the below data.The data can have N number of rows.

```
empname       empid         empnum    
xyz            11               23
qqq            12               34
```

So in the second iteration the echo should give the below output

```
  emp%%20num=11^&:emp%%20Name=xyz^&:emp%%20id=23
    emp%%20num=12^&:emp%%20Name=qqq^&:emp%%20id=34
```

`:arrayparam` is causing the error & was not expected at this time.I am looking for a dynamic load of array.Param can have N number of values delimited by spaces and this should be loaded in to array.

---

**EDIT**

Updating the question more clearly.

I have a param variable which is dynamic ie.it can have N number of values delimited by spaces.As an example the below param has two values.But it can 3 or 4 values delimted by space.each key value pair will be separated by &.This is basically the syntax of tabcmd get.

```
SET PARAM=productname=%%a&productid=%%b empid=%%a&empname=%%b&empad=%%c ...
```

My requirement is to parse param not as string and load each of the values that are delimited by space into an array.Please note that array indexing should be dynamic since the number of parameters in param is dynamic.So in the above case there will be two array index,
`a[0]=productname=%%a&productid=%%b a[1]=empid=%%a&empname=%%b&empad=%%c`

There can be `a[3]` or `a[4]` based on the number of parameter values. So the index should be dynamic.

Once the array is ready, I will feeding this inside a for loop which reads a file having the actual values for the variables mentioned in the param(product name,productid in the first iteration and emp details in the second iteration since we have only two values in this case).So there `%%a`, `%%b`, `%%c` should get replaced with the read actual values.

Why I mentioned not as a string is that if we parse param as a string then the `%%a`, `%%b` values wont get replaced with actual values from file.
I tired to read param in for loop without adding quotes then an error is throwing `& was not expecting at this time`

Can someone provide suggestions to load the array dynamically without considering the param as string and the array index should be dynamic.

TIA

Comment: @Compo Thank you so much for the answer.When i put the set argument in " and hardcode the index as 0 and 1 the results are correct.But my usecase is the array index should be dynamic.In param any number of values can come delimited by space.How can i load the array in that case. For example,if param has 3 values that ar delimited by space then an array fo index 3 should be loaded,it has 4 den array o 4...The number of key value pair will also be changing sometimes 2,3,4..but those will be seperated by &:.

Comment: You obviously have an existing problem, with already written real code. What you need to do is to provide all of your actual code, and the exact problem. Currently you're manually defining a variable `set param=product%%20num=%%c^&:product%%20Name=%%a^&:product%%20id=%%b emp%%20num=%%c^&:emp%%20Name=%%a^&:emp%%20id=%%b` in `config.bat`. `%%a`, `%%b` and `%%c` have no values, unless they're being defined within the `do` portion of a `for` loop, but you haven't got a [tag:for-loop] above. If you're manually defining it, then there's no reason not to define each separately as `a[0]`, `a[1]` etc.

Comment: Additionally, if you're somehow pre-defining `%param%` prior to its use in a [tag:for-loop], you may need to do more work on its content because `%%#` would become `%#`, _(as `%` characters are special in a batch file)_. You'd therefore need it to read `set "param=product%%20num=%%%%c&:product%%20Name=%%%%a&:product%%20id=%%%%b emp%%20num=%%%%c&:emp%%20Name=%%a&:emp%%20id=%%%%b"`. However, as already implied, at that point you must know its content, so it isn't dynamic, it's a static string! You appear to be expecting us to provide a solution for your existing task without fully explaining it!